# Like function which contains space as one of the character in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to use like function which contains space as one of the character in msql.
 In my database, i am having column name as "contractor_id".
This is my code for selecting column name from table.

```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME as a FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '$table'  AND column_name LIKE '%".actor id."%'.
```

Comment: What is `actor id` ? a `PHP` script variable ???

Comment: 'actor id' is a part of 'contr-actor id'

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the quotation marks like

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as a 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = '$table'  
AND column_name LIKE '%actor id%'
```

Or, in case you are generally looking for a column name with a blank in it use

```
... column_name like '% %'
```

Comment: No, this is my code. Even if i removed that quotation,its not working

Comment: $content=['user ','name'];
for($i=0;$i<count($content);$i++)
 {
 $col1 = "";
 $cont=substr($content[$i],0,3);
  $sql1="SELECT COLUMN_NAME as a
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = '$table'
  AND column_name LIKE '%".$dfd."%'";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql1);

Comment: Try and display the actual SQL command to yourself before using it in the mysql_query(). Maybe you can spot the problem then?

Comment: Thank you for answers. I will check.